# How do I identify a paired Bluetooth device that's currently disconnected?

Tags: c#, bluetooth

How do I discover a paired Bluetooth device that's currently disconnected?

I've attempted the following code using the Windows 10 SDK:

```
using Windows.Devices.Enumeration;
using Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.Rfcomm;

var serviceInfoCollection = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort));
```

I've also tried the following:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Management;

public class Win32_UsbDriveWatcher
{
    ManagementEventWatcher m_watcher;

    public delegate void DeviceInsertedEventHandler(object sender, Win32_UsbDriveInsertEventArgs e);

    public event DeviceInsertedEventHandler DeviceInserted;
    public event EventHandler DeviceRemoved;

    public void Start(int pollingInterval)
    {
        try
        {
            var queryString =
              "SELECT * " +
              " FROM __InstanceOperationEvent" +
              " WITHIN " + pollingInterval +
              " WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_PnPEntity'";

            var processQuery = new EventQuery(queryString);

            m_watcher = new ManagementEventWatcher(processQuery);
            m_watcher.EventArrived += EventArrived;
            m_watcher.Start();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    void EventArrived(object sender, EventArrivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var instance = ((PropertyData)(e.NewEvent.Properties["TargetInstance"]));
        var obj = (ManagementBaseObject)instance.Value;
        var args = new Win32_UsbDriveInsertEventArgs();

        if ((string)obj["InterfaceType"] == "BLUETOOTH")
        {
            args.IsCreated = (obj.ClassPath.ClassName == "__InstanceCreationEvent");
            args.DriveName = GetDriveLetterFromDisk((string)obj["Name"]);
            if (args.IsCreated)
            {
                DeviceInserted?.Invoke(this, args);
            }
            else
            {
                DeviceRemoved?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }

    static string GetDriveLetterFromDisk(string name)
    {
        name = name.Replace("\\", "\\\\");

        var query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" + name + "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition";
        var queryDrive = new ObjectQuery(query);
        using (var searcherDrive = new ManagementObjectSearcher(queryDrive))
        {
            foreach (ManagementObject drive in searcherDrive.Get())
            {
                query = "ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" +
                  drive["DeviceID"] +
                  "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition";
                var queryPartition = new ObjectQuery(query);
                using (var searcherPartition = new ManagementObjectSearcher(queryPartition))
                {
                    foreach (ManagementObject disk in searcherPartition.Get())
                    {
                        return (string)disk["Name"];
                    }
                }
            }
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
public class Win32_UsbDriveInsertEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool IsCreated;
    public string DriveName;
}
```

Regardless of the code snippets that I've attempted, I'm still unable to discover paired disconnected devices.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It sounds like your code is looking for currently paired devices. You'd probably need to access whatever internal cache they use to show "these are the devices that have been connected in the past." It may be possible that those are internal to whatever apps show you that, and hidden within the OS for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

There are few way:

1. Use WM_DEVICE_CHANGE message to know when device connected and disconnected.
2. Once you found all paired devices query each for its services. Not available (disconnected) device reports error.
3. Try to connect to device's SDP service using DeviceIOControl (the best way).